# Vote button not remaining red

Tags: bug, android-app

When I vote on a question or answer in the Android app, sometimes the up arrow turns red briefly then the screen flashes ad if it refreshed and the up button is no longer red. The vote count is at its new incremented value and I get an "already voted" type message if I click the arrow button again, so I know my vote registered.

- App Version: 1.0.85
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: VS425PP
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (161331805d4f5)

Comment: Indeed, this is no doubt the most annoying bug, that will likely never be fixed. I share your frustration!